# Running multiple Cox-PH models with tidyr

Tags: r, survival-analysis, tibble, tidy, survival

I have a regular `Surv` object from the `survival` package;

```r
s <- Surv(sample(100:150, 5), sample(c(T, F), 5, replace = T))
```

And a matrix of multiple variables;

```r
df <- data.frame(var1 = rnorm(5),
                 var2 = rnorm(5),
                 var3 = rnorm(5))
```

I need to fit a Cox-PH model for each variable separately. My code currently uses a loop as follows:

```r
for (v in colnames(df)) {
    coxph(s ~ df[[v]])
}
```

Of course, in reality there are thousands of variables and this process takes a bit. I wanted to follow [the answer given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54907726/running-multiple-linear-regressions-across-several-columns-of-a-data-frame-in-r) to try and do it all with `tidyr` but I'm kinda stumped because the predictand isn't a factor, it's a survival object, so I don't quite know how to handle it as part of a tibble.

Comment: Typo? The model should have `s` as the response right?

Comment: Yes, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your response is `s` for the survival model, you can use a nested dataframe similar to the answer you link to, then map the model to the different variables:

library(tidyverse)

```
df_nested <- df %>% pivot_longer(cols = var1:var3) %>% group_by(name) %>% nest()


surv_model <- function(df) {
  coxph(s ~ df$value)
}

df_nested <- df_nested %>% mutate(model = map(data, surv_model))

df_nested
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   name [3]
  name  data             model  
  <chr> <list>           <list> 
1 var1  <tibble [5 x 1]> <coxph>
2 var2  <tibble [5 x 1]> <coxph>
3 var3  <tibble [5 x 1]> <coxph>
```

Comment: So a column in the tibble is itself a list? That sounds like something that I couldn't really work with... But what if I changed the function to only return, say, 3 values from the model? Is it possible to map that directly into 3 columns?

Comment: Its a list of models. You don't have to store data this way, but you asked for a `tidyr` alternative to a for loop and here is one way to do it. Look into `purrr::map` and the `broom` package for how to work with them.

Comment: You could map the predictions from the 3 models into 3 columns. Look into the `add_predictions` function