# Apply glm() by filtering a column by its value in R

Tags: r, function, regression

I have a dataframe with let's call it dependent variable, various independent variables (indicators) and a filtering variable. My goal is to run regressions by filtering different categories in my filtering variable. For example, if I want to run regression for `code == "all"`, I will just take my dataframe, filter the code, and run a regression:

```
sample_tib %>%
    filter(code == "all") %>%
    glm(love ~ ., data = ., family = "gaussian")
```

But there are several problems that I am facing:

1. In my example above my `glm()` will take all columns, not
   excepting the `code`. The desirable input into the regression is
   `love ~ ind1 + ind2 + ... + ind_n`;
2. Filtering by all codes in `code` and running different models is costly and not really the
   thing that I want.

Maybe there exist a function which filters the dataframe, then runs a regression and nests its results in a new dataframe or list? I tried to figure this out and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54907726/running-multiple-linear-regressions-across-several-columns-of-a-data-frame-in-r) question and beautiful Dave Gruenewald's solution. But his way takes only one pattern - `x ~ y`, one dependent and one independent variable. Which is obviously not what I need.

So, is there any elegant solutions or specific packages and functions for this problem?

Data:

```
sample_tib <- data.frame(
  code = c(
    "all",
    "all",
    "all",
    "all",
    "all",
    "all",
    "all",
    "all",
    "all",
    "all",
    "all",
    "all",
    "Data Science",
    "Data Science",
    "Data Science",
    "Data Science",
    "Data Science",
    "Data Science",
    "Data Science",
    "Data Science",
    "Data Science",
    "Data Science",
    "Data Science",
    "Data Science",
    "Data Engineer",
    "Data Engineer",
    "Data Engineer",
    "Data Engineer",
    "Data Engineer",
    "Data Engineer",
    "Data Engineer",
    "Data Engineer",
    "Data Engineer",
    "Data Engineer",
    "Data Engineer",
    "Data Engineer"
  ),
  love = runif(36),
  ind1 = runif(36),
  ind2 = runif(36),
  ind3 = runif(36),
  ind4 = runif(36),
  ind5 = runif(36),
  ind6 = runif(36),
  ind7 = runif(36)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can split the data and apply `glm` to each `code` separately.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

sample_tib %>%
  group_split(code) %>%
  map(function(x) glm(love~., data = select(x, -code), family = "gaussian"))
```

`select(x, -code)` drops `code` columns from the data so you can use `love~.`.

Comment: thank you. and how can i retain categories names as list names?

Comment: If you want the list names use `split(.$code)` instead of `group_split`.

Answer (score 2):

We can use [`nest_by`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/nest_by.html) from `dplyr`

1. We just use `nest_by` to do the grouping
2. Simply create the model in a `list` within `mutate`

NOTE: No other packages other than `dplyr` is used

```
library(dplyr)
sample_tib %>%
    nest_by(code) %>%
    mutate(model = list(glm(love ~ ., data = data, family = 'gaussian'))) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  code                        data model 
  <chr>         <list<tibble[,8]>> <list>
1 all                     [12 × 8] <glm> 
2 Data Engineer           [12 × 8] <glm> 
3 Data Science            [12 × 8] <glm>
```